# ἀλλοτριεπίσκοπος from 1 Peter 4:15

Tags: word-study

1 Peter 4:15 ([ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20peter%204%3A15&version=ESV)) reads:

But let none of you suffer as a murderer or a thief or an evildoer or as **a meddler**.

The emboldened text above is the Greek term [ἀλλοτριεπίσκοπος](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_peter/4-15.htm).

Various commentaries and lexicons that I've read over the years all seem to suggest ἀλλοτριεπίσκοπος refers to any business of others that other men have the responsibility to oversee, in particular the oversight of a man's family by that man as husband and father.

However, I am wondering if a more limited, ecclesiastical model is a better way to understand the term, so that what the author is proscribing is being found guilty of meddling into the bishopric of another pastor/elder in the church, as opposed to any general business that another person may have in life, family or otherwise.

One piece of evidence that might suggest this is the case is that merely five verses later, Simon Peter is clearly addressing elders in the religious community of his audience (See [5:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20peter%205%3A1&version=ESV)).

The question then is, what is the best way of understanding ἀλλοτριεπίσκοπος in the context of 1 Peter 4:15?

Answer (score 1):

First the word ἀλλοτριεπίσκοπος (allotriepiskopos) come from two Greek words "allotrios" and "episkopos"; overseeing others' affairs, i.e. A meddler.  BDAG offers this meaning, "one who meddles in things that do not concern the person, a busybody".

Can such a meaning be construed to mean something like one bishop interfering in the affairs of another parish?  There is no doubt that the above BDAG meaning would include this, but is that Paul's primary intention here?  I believe it is NOT for the following reasons:

- Such an "ecclesiastical" meaning would require that bishops existed in Paul's day and that they were allocated to their bishoprics as the modern practice in some denominations. This requires all the machinery of ordination and appointment about which the NT is completely silent.  "episcopos" in the NT is simply the word for household servant who oversees and was applied to elected elders.
- The other three "sins" in this list, murder, theft and criminal activity, are all definitely non-ecclesiastical, so it would be difficult to single out just one as meaning something specifically ecclesiastical
- Most importantly, the next verse (v16) contrasts these non-ecclesiastical activities with "suffering as a Christian", also implying that the previous list was non-ecclesiastical.

It is readily agreed that from v16 onwards, as the transition in v16 explicitly says, are a series of admonitions to Christians and their leaders.  The Pulpit commentary observes:

> Or as a busybody in other men's matters. This clause represents one
>   Greek word, ἀλλοτριοεπίσκοπος; it means an ἐπίσκοπος, ill-specter,
>   overseer ("bishop" is the modern form of the word), of other men's
>   matters - of things that do not concern him. St. Peter uses the word
>   ἐπίσκοπος only once (1 Peter 2:25), where he describes Christ as the
>   Bishop of our souls. It cannot be taken here in its ecclesiastical
>   sense, "let no man suffer as a bishop in matters which do not concern
>   him; but if as a Christian (bishop), let him not be ashamed." The Jews
>   were often accused of constituting themselves judges and meddling in
>   other men's matters; it may be that the consciousness of spiritual
>   knowledge and high spiritual dignity exposed Christians to the same
>   temptation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by user25930 may be profound, but may also be off-base.

"There is no doubt that the above BDAG meaning would include this, but is that Paul's primary intention here? I believe it is NOT for the following reasons:"  etc./

My take thus far, based on BlueLetterBible/Strongs, indicates the particular word here in 1 Peter 4:15 for meddler/busybody arises only this one time in Scripture.  I have not heard that Paul is the author of 1 Peter, so wonder if anything that follows "... Paul's primary intention..." should carry any weight. Other references, in Pauline letters use a different Greek word to convey the idea of busybody/meddler, and seem related more to a sense of idleness in an endeavor, and not a specific evil act.

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (both, bottom left, below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. If you disagree with an answer you may comment on that answer (when you have sufficient reputation to make comments). But this is the area for independent answers, not related to or referencing other answers. As to someone making a minor slip and saying 'Paul' instead of 'Peter' I do not think that makes everything that follows in-valid. If you look at all that user contributed to the site,over many months, it is significant and valuable.